# C#: Check Actual Date Online?

Tags: c#, datetime

How can I check the actual date and time by using an internet connection? I would like to receive the response from the server as a simple string; I don't want to parse an HTML response.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a post about getting internet time: C#: [Get NIST Internet Time](http://nickstips.wordpress.com/2010/02/12/c-get-nist-internet-time/)

Answer (score 4):

You can find a lot of information on getting date and time from a server [here](http://www.kloth.net/software/timesrv1.php). 

Listed on that page are several protocols that are designed to requesting and retrieving date and time:

- [DAYTIME (RFC 867)](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc867.html)
- [TIME (RFC 868)](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc868.html)
- [NTP (RFC 1305)](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc1305.html)
- [SNTP (RFC 2030)](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2030.html)

From there, you can [easily find](http://www.google.com/search?&q=public+time+servers) some public servers that support one of these protocols. Then it's just a matter of writing some code to access one of these servers in a way that conforms to the protocol spec.

Or you can use some that's already been written and made freely available, for example:

[Here](http://www.csharphelp.com/2007/02/getting-the-datetime-using-the-daytime-protocol-rfc-867/) (DAYTIME protocol) or [Here](http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en&sa=N&cd=1&ct=rc#GawBxmf1je8/NTP/NtpClient.cs&q=ntp%20lang%3ac%23&l=34) (NTP protocol)

Answer (score 0):

You may find [Building Links to World Time Server.com](http://www.worldtimeserver.com/link-info.aspx) helpful. They offer several approaches.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably look at ntp which is a generic standard for syncing date and time.  However windows time already uses that in a domain environment and can be configured to sync against [public servers](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/262680).